# Is there an analogous "pass" keyword for attributes like the one for methods?

Tags: python

I want to define a skeleton class (a class that has doesn't yet have the implementations and initializations for the attributes).

For methods of the class, I can just use `pass`, but how do I do something analogous for the attributes?

e.g.,

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    # what can I use in place of pass here
    self.var1 = pass
    self.var1 = pass
  def method1(self):
    pass
```

Comment: If you just want to have the attributes noted for implementors, you can put them at the top **with a type** where you'd normally put class attributes: `class MyClass: self.var1: SomeType; self.var2: SomeType2; def __init__(self):...`. Confusingly, if they have a type there, they mean instance, not class attributes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you wouldn't use `self` there

Comment: As opposed to suggested `None`, I'd advice `Ellipsis` (which can be written in source code as literal ellipsis, `...`). `None` can be a reasonable default value *in the implementation*, and ellipsis clearly says "hey, please come back and replace me".

Comment: @STerliakov can you do something like `self.var1 = ...` within the constructor?

Comment: @roulette01 yes, of course you can, but remember, that *is an implementation*. the `Ellipsis` object is just an object like any other.

Comment: To note, `pass` _is_ an implementation. You get a method that returns `None` assigned to the class variable. Assigning `None` to the attribute would be analagous. Though you may want to `raise NotImplemented` in the methods instead.

Comment: Oops, trying to write than on one line apparently bypassed by mental checks.

Answer (score 2):

`None` is a good option.

`self.var1 = None`

To test for `None` specifically (to test if it's unset) use the `is` keyword:

`if self.var is None:`

The Python standard library uses `None`:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/threading.py

The popular Python library requests uses `None`:

https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/src/requests/models.py

It's best to follow common patterns than use unfamiliar objects like `Ellipsis`.

Comment: In both your links `None` is **not** a sign of "not implemented placeholder". It is a perfectly valid default value, convenient to use there. The spirit of question is representing a "skeleton" class *during implementation*: when you go top-to-bottom, you inevitably add a bunch of not implemented methods and attributes, leaving more freedom when completing the "bottom" part with actual lower-level code.

Comment: Good point but he specifically wanted a replacement for `pass` in his variable assignment code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not setting the attributes at all. Wait until you have an actual value to initialize them with.

Instead, you can document the fact that real `MyClass` instances will have those attribute by adding some type annotations to `MyClass`. For example, supposing that `var1` will eventually be a `str`, you could define `MyClass` as

```
class MyClass:
    var1: str
    
    def method1(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Static analysis programs (including IDEs and type checkers) will then also be able to validate any accesses to `var1`.

Since you described `MyClass` as a "skeleton" that "doesn't yet have the implementations", there's a good chance what you really want is an [abstract class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). A better definition of `MyClass` might be

```
import abc


class MyClass(abc.ABC):
    var1: str
    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method1(self):
        ...
```

This would prevent `MyClass` from being instantiated directly, so you don't even have to worry about initializing attributes to bogus values. The responsibility for correctly initializing `var1` gets pushed to the subclassess.